# No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1]' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'.' C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Vengo una vez mas con otro inconveniente en `Entity Framewrok` realizo el siguiente código para poder mostrar una secuencia tipo `0001` en un textbox pero al momento de abrir el formulario me arroja el error descrito en la pregunta.

```
 public void ID_Odontologo(TextBox txtCodigo)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var Cod_Odo = 0;
                String TempCodPac = null;
                var ultimo_Odon = (from t in db.TBL_ODONTOLOGO
                                   orderby t.ODONT_CODIGO
                                   select t).ToList();
                if (ultimo_Odon == null) <-- AQUI EN ESTE IF MARCA EL ERROR.
                {
                    txtCodigo.Text = "0001"; 
                }
                else if (ultimo_Odon != null)
                {
                    Cod_Odo = (ultimo_Odon != null) ?
                           Convert.ToInt32(ultimo_Odon) + 1 :
                           1;
                    if (Cod_Odo < 10)
                    {
                        TempCodPac = String.Concat("000", Convert.ToString(Cod_Odo));
                        txtCodigo.Text+= TempCodPac;
                    }
                    else if (Cod_Odo >= 10 && Cod_Odo <= 11)
                    {
                        TempCodPac = String.Concat("00", Convert.ToString(Cod_Odo));
                        txtCodigo.Text += TempCodPac;
                    }
                    else if (Cod_Odo > 10 && Cod_Odo < 100)
                    {
                        TempCodPac = String.Concat("00", Convert.ToString(Cod_Odo));
                        txtCodigo.Text += TempCodPac;
                    }
                    else if (Cod_Odo >= 100 && Cod_Odo <= 101)
                    {
                        TempCodPac = String.Concat("0", Convert.ToString(Cod_Odo));
                        txtCodigo.Text += TempCodPac;
                    }
                    else if (Cod_Odo > 100 && Cod_Odo < 1000)
                    {
                        TempCodPac = String.Concat("0", Convert.ToString(Cod_Odo));
                        txtCodigo.Text += TempCodPac;
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Adjunto la imagen en donde cae en error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy formulando incorrectamente para que arroja ese error.

Comment: Dices "AQUI EN ESTE IF MARCA EL ERROR", que error te marca?

Comment: Creo que tu error mas bien es este: *Convert.ToInt32(ultimo_Odon)* No puedes c9nvertrir una lista a int.

Comment: No llega a esa linea directamente se queda en la primera validacion.

Comment: Se queda en esa línea porque ya no puede continuar con la siguiente. Comenta la linea donde haces el Convert y ejecuta de nuevo para que lo compruebes. Para ello reemplaza el convertir por un número entero digamos  0, para dejar la instrucción. Verás que el error ya no te sale.

Comment: En todo caso, cuando llegues a esa línea vas a tener otro problema

Comment: Por último, en todo el código que has puesto,  quien crees que el unico implementa la inteefaz IConvertible? Pues Convert.

Comment: El método de extensión `ToList()` para `IEnumerable` crea una nueva instancia del objeto `List<T>` de lista, por lo que es inútil validar si es `null`. Por otra parte, ¿Porqué `ultimo_Odon` es una lista, no debería ser un solo elemento, traído por ejemplo con el método de extensión `Last()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo de tu código es que quieres traer el último código y sumarle +1, para eso puedes ocupar `FirstOrDefault` o `LastOrDefault` (dependiendo del orden), otro función que puede servir es `Max`. Luego para agregar ceros a la izquierda puedes usar `PadLeft`, quedando tu código de esta manera:

```
public void ID_Odontologo(TextBox txtCodigo){
  int code = 1;
  var odon = db.TBL_ODONTOLOGO.OrderByDescending(a=>a.ODONT_CODIGO).FirstOrDefault();

  if(odon !=null){
    code+=odon.ODONT_CODIGO;
  }
  txtCodigo.Text = code.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');

}
```

Comment: Gracias campeón!, lo único que habría que añadir es --> code += Convert.ToInt32(odon.ODONT_CODIGO);